# Insert xml data in cassandra table using cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

I am new to cassandra and i need to insert data in my table in cassandra. I have the following table.

```
Create TABLE test.EVENT(
Id int PRIMARY KEY,
Event_data text
);
```

and i am trying to insert data as follows.

```
INSERT INTO test.EVENT(Id, EVENT_DATA) VALUES (1,"<note> </note>");
```

But i always get an error like this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\cassandra\bin\\cqlsh.py", line 
847, in get_input_line
self.lastcmd = raw_input(prompt).decode(self.encoding)
File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 56: 
invalid start byte
WARNING: console codepage must be set to cp65001 to support utf-8 encoding 
on Windows platforms.
If you experience encoding problems, change your console codepage with 'chcp 
65001' before starting cqlsh.
```

What is the correct way to insert XML data in Cassandra? Is my table structure wrong ? Or am i inserting data in wrong way ?

Comment: use single quotes to enter text column `cqlsh> INSERT INTO test.EVENT(Id, EVENT_DATA) VALUES (1,'<note> </note>');`

Comment: that did not work out

Comment: I ran the same Insert query(with single quotes) and it is working for me. I'm using cassandra-3.7.

Comment: Can you try to insert some sample text data instead of XML to same table and check if the problem exists.

Comment: It is working for me now thanks :) It appears some special character was the trouble.

Comment: Good to hear that :)